# OpenAI, Python, Delete File

Tags: python, file, delete-file, openai-api

In order to test some OpenAI file functionalities (Answer, Search etc.), I created several files using python through the OpenAI API.

As per OpenAI [files documentation][1] I am now trying to delete the file(s) I created as follows:

```
openai.File("file-CQ0tfZ4p3Hihlbwi1tQYmZV2").delete()
```

the error I get is as follows:

```
TypeError: delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sid'
```

I know the file exists as I am able to print it's properties.
My coding ability is fairly basic... how can I delete some...or all the files.

The entire code snippet is as follows:

```
import openai

#set environment variable and print
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = '*************************'
os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')

openai.File("file-CQ0tfZ4p3Hihlbwi1tQYmZV2").delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the OpenAI documentation.

You have to delete as follow :

`openai.File.delete("file-CQ0tfZ4p3Hihlbwi1tQYmZV2")`

instead of

`openai.File("file-CQ0tfZ4p3Hihlbwi1tQYmZV2").delete()`